# how to add images in custom list view after clicking on Image

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to take image from layout. and when a user select any image then it will be displayed on custom list view. what i have achieved now when first time i click on image it is displayed on custom list view but when i select image for the second time, it override the image over the first one. here is the code for review

here is my main class

```
package com.example.zeus_technologies.customlistview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;

String[] itemname ={
        "Safari",
};
Integer[] imgid={
        R.drawable.a,
        R.drawable.ab,
        R.drawable.abc,
        R.drawable.abcd,
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 //   list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    final Context context=this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ImageView[] im = new ImageView[4];
    im[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
    im[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
    im[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview3);
    im[3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview4);

    im[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter((Activity) context,itemname, imgid[0]);

                         list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    });
    im[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


           CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter((Activity) context, itemname, imgid[1]);

            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    });
}
```

and here is my list adapter class
    package com.example.zeus_technologies.customlistview;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer imgid;
public CustomListAdapter(Activity context,String[] itemname ,Integer imgid)           {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
   this.imgid=imgid;
}

 public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    //TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    //TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
     imageView.setImageResource(imgid);

     ///extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
   return rowView;

};
```

}

one more thing. i have already tried to make adapter object out from onClickListener. but still its not working

Comment: I think you need to make `list(Listview)` `adpter` **null** before adding new `adpter`. Try like this `list.setAdapter(null);` before `list.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: You don't want to set a new adapter to your listview everytime the data changes. You should set the adapter to the listview in your `onCreate` method with your empty dataset and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` everytime you add a new item to your dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to set a new adapter every time you add a new item to it, what you want to do is set the adapter to the listview once, and update the underlying dataset and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Something like this (pseudo code):

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private List<ListItem> dataSet;

    private ListView list;

    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    private ImageView imageview1, imageview2, imageview3, imageview4;

    private Integer[] ids = {
        R.drawable.first,
        R.drawable.second,
        R.drawable.third,
        R.drawable.fourth,
    };

    private String[] names = {
        "First",
        "Second",
        "Third",
        "Fourth",
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        dataSet = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, dataSet);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        imageview1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        imageview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
        imageview3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview3);
        imageview4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview4);

        imageview1.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageview2.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageview3.setOnClickListener(this);
        imageview4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int selectedImage;

        if (v == imageview1) {
            selectedImage = 0;
        } else if (v == imageview2) {
            selectedImage = 1;
        } else if (v == imageview3) {
            selectedImage = 2;
        } else {
            selectedImage = 3;
        }

        dataSet.add(new ListItem(names[selectedImage], ids[selectedImage]));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context context;

    private final List<ListItem> dataSet;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<ListItem> dataSet) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.dataSet = dataSet;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dataSet.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        ListItem item = dataSet.get(position);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        imageView.setImageResource(item.getId());
        textView.setText(item.getName());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

ListItem:

```
public class ListItem {

    private String name;
    private int id;

    public ListItem(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is working now. thnx it was really a great help to me :)

Comment: Good to hear, if this solved the problem please accept my answer.